# ¿Cómo se traduciría "on the side"?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario

Querría decir a los efectos de "I majored in something at university, but also studied Spanish **on the side**." Lo único que se me ocurre es "me especialicé en un algo sujeto, además **aparte** estudiaba poco del castellano." ¿Eso sería aceptable? Muchísimas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible traducción para "on the side" sería "adicionalmente" o "por otro lado". Si existe simultaneidad, se podría usar "paralelamente" o "al mismo tiempo".

- Me especialicé en X tema en la universidad, y adicionalmente estudié algo de español.
- Me especialicé en X tema en la universidad, y por otro lado estudié algo de español.

El adverbio "aparte" con sentido de adición, al igual que la locución preposicional "aparte de", son más comunes en la lengua oral que en la escrita.

Comment: I don't think it's por otro lado or adicionalmente. on the side means outside of official channels.

Comment: Well, you could say something like "en forma complementaria," but I don't think it makes any significant difference. The idea OP wanted to convey, it seems to me, is that X was the main course of study and Spanish was a secondary interest. As written, I think the Spanish sentence expresses the idea quite accurately.

Comment: Generally speaking, this is slang for an extra-marital fling. He had a piece on the side. On the side means not via official channels. It is not secondary. It means not in a/the school or university not unofficially. No grading.

Comment: I understand. It would be something like "non-collegiate," right? OP wanted to say that in Spanish. What you refer to would be "una relación paralela" in Spanish. Then, using "paralelamente, estudié algo de español" (which I included in my answer) would be spot on, it seems to me.